# how to move arrows using swiper?

Tags: css, next.js, swiper.js, react-swiper, react-native-swiper

This is my carousel but here when I want to configure the swiper-button the arrows are very far from the image, any idea how to make them closer (modify their position)?

`````
  effect={'coverflow'}
  grabCursor={false}
  centeredSlides={true}
  slidesPerView={'3'}
  rewind={true}
  coverflowEffect={{
     rotate: 0,
     stretch: 0,
     depth: 30,
     modifier: 20,
     slideShadows: false,
   }}
 preventClicks={true}
 navigation={true}
 pagination={true}
 modules={[EffectCoverflow, Pagination]}
 className="mySwiperDesktop">````


I tried modifying the numbers in the width (44*27), but when i change the resolution the arrow goes out the screen

width: calc(var(--swiper-navigation-size)/ 44 * 27)
`````